# Is symmetric matrix over a field F always diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

I wonder if the following statement is true or not:

An $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over a field $F$ is diagonalizable if it is symmetric.

If the field $F$ is $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, it is true. I wonder if it is true for some other finite fields, such as $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Your claim about $F=\mathbb C$ is false. It is known that every complex square matrix is similar to some complex symmetric matrix. So, not all complex symmetric matrices are diagonalisable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not true.  For example, the matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&1} \in \Bbb Z_2^{2 \times 2}
$$
fails to be diagonalizable since it is non-zero, but nilpotent.  In general: if $x$ is the column-vector of $n$ $1$s, then $xx^T$ fails to be diagonalizable over $\Bbb Z_n$ for the same reason.