# Let L be a Lie algebra with dim(L)=dim(L′)=3. Prove or disprove that there is a change of basis matrix is diagonal.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

> **Prove or disprove:** Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over **any** field $F$ with $\dim(L)=\dim(L')=3$. Then there exists a basis $\{x,y,z\}$ of $L$ such that the change of basis matrix from $\{[y,z],[z,x],[x,y]\}$ to $\{x,y,z\}$ is diagonal.

My thinking (Prove):
Suppose
$$
\begin{bmatrix}[y,z] \\ [z,x] \\ [x,y] \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $i\neq 0$, let $z'=gx+hy+iz$ then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}[y,z'] \\ [z',x] \\ [x,y] \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}a'&b'&c'\\d'&e'&f'\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z'\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $c'\neq 0$, let $\alpha=f'/c'$ and $x'=x+\alpha y$ then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}[y,z'] \\ [z',x'] \\ [x',y] \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}a''&b''&c''\\d''&e''&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y\\z'\end{bmatrix}.
$$
$$
\vdots
$$
If we can arrive that 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}[y',z'] \\ [z',x'] \\ [x',y'] \end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}\theta&0&0\\0&\phi&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{bmatrix}
$$
then we are done. But it is too tedious to exhaust all cases. I hope there is a smarter approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It essentially goes like this. Since $L=L'$, the Lie algebra $L$ is simple.
Simple $3$-dimensional Lie algebras are classified over an arbitrary field, see
for example Strade's article on Lie algebras in small dimensions. 
Denote the base change matrix by $M_{x,y,z}$. A lengthy calculation with the Jacobi identity shows that $M_{x,y,z}$ is in fact symmetric. It then follows from linear algebra that a basis for $L$ can be chosen so that $M_{x,y,z}$ is diagonal, see for example H. Anton: Elementary Linear Algebra, Eighth Edition, John Wiley & Sons, Inc, page $357$. 
The case of characteristic $p=2$ is more difficult, because there we cannot diagonalize every symmetric matrix. 
For more details then see [this thesis](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdf/research/y4_fowlerwright.pdf), page $13-14$.

Comment: The symmetry property is amazing, but the diagonalbility of symmetric matrix for any field is not true in general (  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096374 ).

Comment: But I can still complete it by exhaustion since it becomes simple by the symmetry property, if it is true. Thank a lot !

Comment: Yes indeed, see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507527/diagonalizability-of-symmetric-bilinear-forms-over-fields-of-characteristic-2?noredirect=1&lq=1). It makes sense to check the linked thesis on this; how they solve this in characteristic $2$.